# @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument error in monorepo

Tags: typescript, eslint, monorepo, typescript-eslint

I am having trouble with the "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument" rule and don't really understand what is causing
the error. It's so frustrating that I am not able to fix it. It shows up when I'm trying to import a function from a
package that is in the same workspace.

So in server.ts:

```js
// apps/scraper/src/server.ts
import {repo} from "db";

...
const profileId = await repo.profile.create({}); // <-- this is where the error shows up eslint thinks repo is any
...
```

And how I am exporting the function in db:

```js
// apps/db/index.ts
import * as user from "./src/repositories/user";
import listProfiles from "./src/usecases/list-profiles";

export const repo = {
    user,
    ...
};

export const usecase = {
    listProfiles,
    ...
}
```

I tried different ways to import, which none of them worked and I still get the same error:

- `import {repo} from "db";`
- `import {userFn} from "db/src/repositories/user.ts";`
- `import {userFn} from "db/dist/src/repositories/user.js";`

So I have a turbo repo, which has following structure:

```
    apps
    ├── scraper
    │   ├── src
    │   │   ├── server.ts
    │   ├── package.json
    │   ├── tsconfig.json
    packages
    ├── db
    │   ├── src
    │   │   ├── repositories
    │   │   │   ├── user.ts
    │   ├── index.ts
    │   ├── package.json
    │   ├── tsconfig.json
    tsconfig.json
    package.json
```

For the scraper app, I have these:

```json
// apps/scraper/tsconfig.json

{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "target": "ES2015",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    },
    "strict": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

```json
// apps/scraper/package.json
{
  "name": "scraper",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "db": "workspace:*",
    "logger": "workspace:*",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@acme/eslint-config": "workspace:*",
    "dotenv-cli": "^7.2.1",
    "tsc-alias": "^1.8.7",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    ...
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "extends": [
      "@acme/eslint-config/base"
    ]
  }
}
```

For the db package, I have these:

```json
// packages/db/tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
    "index.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": false,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "dist"
  }
}
```

```json
// packages/db/package.json
{
  "name": "db",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "logger": "workspace:*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "@acme/eslint-config": "workspace:*"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "extends": [
      "@acme/eslint-config/base"
    ]
  }
}
```

My root tsconfig is this:

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "no-explicit-any": "off"
  },
  "include": [
    ".prettierrc.cjs"
  ]
}
```

And my base eslint config is:

```json
// packages/config/eslint/base.js

/** @type {import("eslint").Linter.Config} */
const config = {
  extends: [
    "turbo",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-type-checked",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/stylistic-type-checked",
    "prettier"
  ],
  env: {
    es2022: true,
    node: true
  },
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    project: true
  },
  plugins: [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "import"
  ],
  rules: {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
      "error",
      {
        argsIgnorePattern: "^_",
        varsIgnorePattern: "^_"
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports": [
      "warn",
      {
        prefer: "type-imports",
        fixStyle: "separate-type-imports"
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises": [
      2,
      {
        checksVoidReturn: {
          attributes: false
        }
      }
    ],
    "import/consistent-type-specifier-style": [
      "error",
      "prefer-top-level"
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-definitions": "off"
  },
  ignorePatterns: [
    "**/.eslintrc.cjs",
    "**/*.config.js",
    "**/*.config.cjs",
    "packages/config/**",
    ".next",
    "dist",
    "pnpm-lock.yaml"
  ],
  reportUnusedDisableDirectives: true
};

module.exports = config;
```

Edit: The eslint error says:

`ESLint: Unsafe call of an "any" typed value.(@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call)`

`ESLint: Unsafe member access .profile on an "any" value.(@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access`

However when I hover over the "repo" editor is able to pickup the correct type information from the **db** package. Which is the main confusing part for me. Typescript is able to infer the types but eslint is giving error because it thinks it's any.

Comment: 1. What _specifically_ does the error say, in full? 2. If you hover over `create` in `repo.profile.create({})` what does your editor say the type of that function is?

Comment: @AlexWayne Just to make it obvious for everyone I have edited the question and added at the end of the post

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue after many trial & errors

For anyone who is experiencing similar problem I can try to explain what I understood, even though I'm not configs expert by any means so take my words with caution.

In my monorepo setup (apps,packages etc.), I have added `types: ["db"]` into my `apps/scraper`,because what I realised is that even though typescript is intelligent to infer the types you have to explicitly tell where the types coming from for eslint. And since my eslint settings are dependent on tsconfig I had to add compilerOptions.types property in order for eslint to figure out the types.